# Do multiple spark applications running on yarn have any impact on each other?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

Do multiple spark jobs running on yarn have any impact on each other?
e.g. If the traffic on one streaming job increases too much does it have any effect on second job? Will it slow it down or any other consequences?

I have enough resources for both of the applications to run concurrently.

Comment: How do you run multiple jobs? Are "spark applications" (in the title) the "multiple spark jobs" (in the body)? Do they belong to the same application? Do they use the same queue? Do the jobs execute one by one (serially) or on separate threads? Answers to the questions matter to be precise with the answer (and be concise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they do. Depending on how your scheduler is set up (static vs dynamic) they either share just the network output (important for shuffles) and disk throughput (important for shuffles, reading in of data locally or on HDFS, writing away data locally or on HDFS) or also the memory and CPUs if it's on dynamic allocation. Still, running your two jobs on parallel as opposed to sequentially will benefit on average, due to the network and disk resources not being used constantly. This mostly depends on the amount of shuffling necessary in your jobs.